# Run two docker-compose files one after another, tiangolo image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I'm quite newbie with docker, so i found this image, which has pre-installed [flask-uwsgi-nginx](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker) and I run it with following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: ./
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3'
 services:
  web:
   volumes:
    - ./app:/app
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   ports:
    - "80:80"
   environment:
    - FLASK_APP=app/main.py
    - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    - 'RUN=flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80'
```

My question is, do i really need to run it with two compose files ? if so, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use two files. You could merge these two files into one and just use it.

The second file overwrites already present settings from the first one. This can be useful in some situations. You could use different "overwrite" files to test different settings.

For example you are developing a web app. This web app has a regular configuration that is valid in any case. Those configs will be in `docker-compose.yml`. Now you start it during development in "dev mode". This mode has some configurations that you pass via `docker-compose.dev.yml`. You start your app with those two files and can work locally. After finishing your work, you want to test your app in "production mode". All configs for this mode reside in another file, namely `docker-compose.prod.yml`. You can now start the app in this mode, just by exchanging the second `-f` argument in `docker-compose up`.

The filenames `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` are not mandatory. If these files are present they are used per default.

Comment: In which case it could be useful to use two files ?

Comment: I added an example to my answer.